# Spring data @Query joda datetime postgresql exception

Tags: postgresql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an Entity with 2 Columns with joda DateTime.

```
@Column(name = "track_start", columnDefinition= "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime start;

@Column(name = "tracke_end", columnDefinition= "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime end;
```

Then I have a Spring data Repository with a find method:

```
@Query("SELECT tt FROM Timetrack tt "
        + "WHERE (:dateFrom is null OR tt.start >= :dateFrom) "
        + "AND (:dateTo is null OR tt.end <= :dateTo)")
Page<Timetrack> findBy(@Param("dateFrom") DateTime dateFrom,
                       @Param("dateTo") DateTime dateTo,
                       Pageable pageable);
```

If I call that finder method I got an Exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $2
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
```

If I change the @Param to Date instead of DateTime I got this Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Fri Jun 01 19:26:44 CEST 2018] did not match expected type [org.joda.time.DateTime (n/a)]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:897)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.access$000(QueryImpl.java:61)
```

So does somebody have an idea?

Here the logging output from hibernate:

```
Hibernate: select timetrack0_.id as id1_6_, timetrack0_.created as created2_6_, timetrack0_.entity_status as entity_s3_6_, timetrack0_.updated as updated4_6_, timetrack0_.user_identity_id as user_ide9_6_, timetrack0_.tracke_end as tracke_e5_6_, timetrack0_.frozen_at as frozen_a6_6_, timetrack0_.invoice_id as invoice10_6_, timetrack0_.project_id as project11_6_, timetrack0_.track_start as track_st7_6_, timetrack0_.task as task8_6_ from timetrack timetrack0_ where ( timetrack0_.entity_status = 'active') and (? is null or timetrack0_.track_start>=?) and (? is null or timetrack0_.tracke_end<=?) order by timetrack0_.track_start asc limit ? offset ?
2018-06-09 21:32:05.804 TRACE 14006 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2018-06-09 20:32:05.604]
2018-06-09 21:32:05.806 TRACE 14006 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2018-06-09 20:32:05.604]
2018-06-09 21:32:05.808 TRACE 14006 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2018-06-10 02:32:05.604]
2018-06-09 21:32:05.809 TRACE 14006 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2018-06-10 02:32:05.604]
```

Comment: Could you add the log showing the SQL statement being executed including its bind parameters?
Also, could you try simpler examples (just one usage of the parameter, just one parameter, no pageable)?

Comment: I added the logging of the SQL statements

Comment: Interesting. Does it work with a normal java.util.Date or one of the java 8 date types?

Comment: I tried it with LocalDateTime of java.time and it works, I will refactor the code to the java time api. :-)

Comment: did you resolve this issue? have the same here

Comment: Hi @ErdincAy No I didn't, since java 8 datetime api, I would say joda datetime is obsolete.